# How to change folder icon in C Drive

Tags: windows

I want to change the folder icon in C drive. When I go onto the tab "Customize" in folder Properties, choose an icon and then apply, nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**FileTypesMan**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html),a nirsoft tool that allows you to do a lot of things.

- Dowload [**FileTypesMan**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) and open it.
- Locate your type of file (like image, or folder for exemple)
- Click on it and select "***Edit Selected File Type***"
- Change defaut icon and confirm

An example for png file : 
[Example to change png type files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zufa.png)